# How to change data type and add column with migration without losing data? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

My migration is like this :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id_test');
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('tests');
}
```

I want to change data type and add column in table test. Then update table in database. I edit like this :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('id_test', 18);
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('tests');
}
```

Then I run : `php artisan migrate:refresh`

I lost my data in database

Is there any people who can help me?

Comment: Simple: Create a *new* migration. Don't edit the old one. Add your new column in the `up()` method, and remove it in the `down()` method. Then just `php artisan migrate` to run the change. `php artisan migrate:rollback` to reverse it.

Comment: You can learn more about migrations by [reading the very thorough documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new migration file using below command :

```
php artisan make:migration name_of_your_file
```

And its function should be like this

```
    public function up()
        {
            Schema::table('tests', function($table) {
                  $table->renameColumn('id_test', 'id');
                  $table->string('id_test', 18);
            });
        }


   public function down()
        {
            Schema::table('tests', function($table) {
                 $table->dropColumn('id_test');
            });
        }
```

Now just run below command

```
php artisan migrate
```

Note : Dont use `refresh` it deletes the data

To know more about Laravel Migration refer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#modifying-columns

Comment: Seems I need your help. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788737/why-the-deleted-data-still-appear-in-the-interface

Comment: Question, why do I need to call dropColumn in the down() function?